# MySql select question

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a search engine. I have to select some data from a table when a user types in the search keywords.

I want to find an alternative to 'LIKE':

```
SELECT id,text FROM example WHERE text LIKE '$search'
```

Because the text column has usually loads of words in it and the search term always contains a few words, I don't get accurate results.
Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered FULLTEXT searches?  I would give more information on them myself, but I'm not great at MySQL, really!  A quick google will tell give you more information on them, though, if you are interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called full-text indexing, but currently it's not supported in InnoDB, only in MyISAM. Alternative is to use third-party indexing, like Lucene, Solr (which provides web service access on top on Lucene), Sphinx...

Answer (score 0):

If your table is MyISAM, you can enable full text searching:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT idx_text (`text`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [MySQL Fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) mechanism, it provides natural language searches in a fairly easy to use way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a search engine is using a tree data structure for fast lookups and some sort of a graph to weight the search result. Maybe you want to look into a trie data structure and space-filling-curve. The latter is useful if you want to compare 2 documents. For example if you sort and count all the words you can do a heat map.